# Как перенести файл или каталог на рабочий стол?

Tags: linux

Как перенести папку `/var/www` на рабочий стол? Что бы не потерялась работоспобность.

Comment: Саша , вы зря отредактировали , вопрос не в файле или  в каталоге а именно в Linux и именно это в названии должно быть

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Первый вопрос - зачем такой ужас городить.

И ответ - сделайте символическую ссылку при помощи команды

```
ln -s /var/www ~/Desktop/www
```

Comment: чёто система пишет что desctop не является каталогом - это можно как то решить ?

Comment: Ну вам в примере вроде через `k` написали, а вы через `c` пишите. А вообще конечно посмотрите как у вас каталог рабочего стола называется

Comment: @LenovoID У меня на одном дебиане, например, он так и называется `"Рабочий стол"`

Comment: да это я здесь ошибся , там всё ровно , терминал ошибок не прощеает , хотя спасибо , на самом деле лишнее это , мух и катлеты не буду путать , спасибо прошу рощение , не надо это

Answer (score 5):

в нужном каталоге можно сделать [символическую ссылку](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0) на файл или каталог:

```
$ ln -s /var/www /нужный/каталог/
```

как узнать имя каталога, выполняющего функции «рабочего стола»? обычно это `~/Desktop`, но, во-первых, это имя может быть локализовано, во-вторых, это имя может быть произвольно изменено пользователем.

текущее значение для любого из «стандартных» каталогов пользователя (речь о стандартах [freedesktop.org, ранее xdg](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org)) можно узнать с помощью программы `xdg-user-dir`, запущенной с одним из параметров:

```
DESKTOP
DOWNLOAD
TEMPLATES
PUBLICSHARE
DOCUMENTS
MUSIC
PICTURES
VIDEOS
```

в применении к текущему вопросу:

```
$ ln -s /var/www "$(xdg-user-dir DESKTOP)"
```

доп. информация — `man xdg-user-dir`

---

кстати, изменить текущее имя для любого «стандартного» каталога можно с помощью программы `xdg-user-dirs-update`, доп. информация — `man xdg-user-dirs-update`.

Comment: это лишнее , спасибо за вашу статью , полезно но лишнее я это понял уже , прекрасно работается и из var/www

Comment: @LenovoID, никакого «переноса» и не происходит. всё остаётся там, где есть.

Comment: Саша и для чего вы отредактировали название ?

Comment: @LenovoID, прежний заголовок, по-моему, был совершенно неинформативен.

Comment: ну конечно ваше право , но linux_оиды  поняли